# Soundcloud API 401 error when resolving song/user url

Tags: ruby, soundcloud

Whenever I try to resolve a url to get an id for a song, it returns a 401 error.  My client works fine for other operations (GET: /me, POST: /me/followings/[id]).  Here's the code I'm using with the soundcloud gem:

```
client.get('/resolve', url: "http://soundcloud.com/stuart-mckeown/darius-bassiray-consortium-of")
```

Comment: Using the api console, this returns a 302 (which is expected behaviour).  Perhaps this is a bug with the gem?  Url:

https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.format?consumer_key=apigee&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com%2Fstuart-mckeown%2Fdarius-bassiray-consortium-of

Comment: Do you know the id of the track you want to get or just the URL?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `https` instead of `http`?

Comment: Might be another issue because that worked for me I got back Soundcloud::HashResponseWrapper artwork_url=nil attachments_uri="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/61784549/attachments" bpm=nil comment_count=0 commentable=true created_at="2012/10/01 06:01:18 +0000" description="Remix that didn't make it onto the final release, enjoy!"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took me a little while to figure out, but you need to send the client id along as well:

`client.get('/resolve', :url => url, :client_id => ENV['SOUNDCLOUD_ID'])`